# Side-bar Navigation pattern

Tags: user-behavior, interface, users, human-interface-guideline, experience

I recently discovered a new UI pattern for the hamburger menu, displayed in the centre of a sidebar, even for e-commerce sites, but I can't find any resources/inspirations or examples. I'm wondering if I'm naming it correctly or if it's a new trend for 2023. Do you know of any other resources on this topic? like images on dribble etc?
referenc [www.sketchin.com](http://www.sketchin.com) [image]

Answer (score 1):

The pattern feels a little bit more complicated than a typical hamburger menu that is persistent at the top of the screen. It combines a few different elements that I have seen in different menu and navigation designs, so I would say that it is a custom navigation.

- It works the same for desktop and mobile, whereas a hamburger menu is usually seen for mobile views to provide more room in a narrower viewing window with mobile devices (although I haven't seen effective designs for foldable devices yet).
- It only appears when you navigate away from a top level section of the website, whereas if you are at a top level section the full menu is show as a normal top level navigation
- It makes the icon at the top of the left hand side redundant (I clicked it and there doesn't seem to be a function), but it makes sense since the navigation menu is on the side instead of at the top

So I see it as a highly customised navigation design pattern used to differentiate the site and give it an unusual look and feel.